# GMAIL Login works with android but not in browser

Tags: browser, gmail, login, android

I have a very strange problem. Every time I try to login to Gmail (https://mail.google.com/) with my username and my password over a browser (Firefox, Chrome & Internet Explorer), I cannot login. It says: "Username or Password incorrect".

If I try to do the same with an Android based browser (on mobile phone and Kindle Fire) the login works just fine.

I replicated the problem on four different computers with Linux (Mint Xcfe), Windows Vista& Windows 7) over the course of a week.

It just drives me crazy. Did anyone have the same problem? Or found a solution?

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Have you tried typing the password into notepad where it's not masked, just to make sure all your keys are working and CAPS aren't on?

Answer (score 1):

Change your password to something different then try it on both, if the it happens again, update the post.

Answer (score 0):

try to login to https://accounts.google.com from your browser and look for account activity reports, or try updating your settings from there.